# I am getting Command find failed: Error=16500, RetryAfterMs=64, Error while Fetching Record Count in Azure Cosmos Db

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

i am fetching total number of count(near about 1500 record) from **azure cosmosdb** and its giving me following error

[Error Detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZATC.png)

here is my code

[Code Detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcNuO.png)

```
getCountFilter = getCountBuilder.Eq("business_id", usermodel[0].business_id) & getCountBuilder.In("user_id", userlist) & getCountBuilder.Eq("status", 1);
                    getAllCountForApproved = getleavebyidconnection.GetFilteredCount(getCountFilter);
     public virtual long GetFilteredCount(FilterDefinition<T> filter = null)
            {
                if (filter == null)
                {
                    return collection.Count((FilterDefinition<T>.Empty));
                }
                else
                {

                    return collection.Count(filter);
                }
            }
```

i want a count only , if count is less its work fine but if count is more then  thousand(1000) its give me error

can some one help me

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: @mjwills Code has been added

Comment: Does https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-troubleshoot or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48064897/cosmos-db-mongo-api-how-to-manage-request-rate-is-large-condition help?

Comment: What did you end up doing? Having the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Based on https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-troubleshoot:

The error code means:

> The total number of request units consumed is more than the provisioned request-unit rate for the collection and has been throttled.
>
> Consider scaling the throughput assigned to a container or a set of containers from the Azure portal or you can retry the operation.

The `RetryAfterMs` is the milliseconds you have to wait in order to retry the operation based on your provisioned [RU/s](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/request-units).